# After adding header view, scroll to bottom of UITableView cause NSException

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, swift3, nsindexpath

I have a method that scrolls my `UITableView` to the bottom:

```
func tableViewScrollToBottom(_ animated: Bool) {

    let delay = 0.1 * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC)
    let time = DispatchTime.now() + Double(Int64(delay)) / Double(NSEC_PER_SEC)

    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: time, execute: {
        print(self.tview.numberOfRows(inSection: 0))
        print(self.tview.numberOfSections)
        let indexPath = IndexPath(row: self.tview.numberOfRows(inSection: 0), section: self.tview.numberOfSections)
        print(indexPath)
        print("it will crash now")
        self.tview.scrollToRow(at: indexPath, at: .bottom, animated: animated)

    })
}
```

it worked well before, however when I added Header View - it crashes.

I see in the console:

```
8
1
[1, 8]
it will crash now
```

so I do not understand why this line:

```
self.tview.scrollToRow(at: indexPath, at: .bottom, animated: animated)
```

causes crash. What am I missing here?

Comment: If there is 8 rows in your section then the last row is row 7.  Likewise, if there is 1 section then the last section is section 0.  You need to subtract 1 from both the row and section of the index path you are trying to scroll to.

Comment: @dan of course you're right. Bother to add it as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have problem with this

```
let indexPath = IndexPath(row: self.tview.numberOfRows(inSection: 0), section: self.tview.numberOfSections)
```

Try doing -1

```
let indexPath = IndexPath(row: self.tview.numberOfRows(inSection: 0)-1, section: self.tview.numberOfSections-1)
```